# Entity framework InvalidOperationException when deleting and adding related objects

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I get

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.'

when running next code:

```
using (var context = new entities.Model1())
{
  var entity = context.MeetingActivities
    .Include(i => i.Participants)
    .Single(m => m.ActivityId == 424);

  // this way delete actually works
  //int[] participantList = entity.Participants.Select(p => p.Id).ToArray();
  //List<entities.Participant> list = context.Participants.Where(p => participantList.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();
  //context.Participants.RemoveRange(list);

  // delete all participants, doesn't work
  while (entity.Participants.Count > 0)
  {
    entity.Participants.Remove(entity.Participants.First());
  }

  // insert new participant
  entity.Participants.Add(new entities.Participant()
  {
    Participant_DisplayName = "testName",
    MeetingActivityId = entity.Id,
    ParticipantId = 4111
  });

  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

The relationship between MeetingActivity and Participants is **one-to-many**. **On one meeting there can be one or more participants**. Participant table has next columns:

- Id (autoincrement)
- ParticipantId (foreign key to table Customer)
- Participant_DisplayName (so we don't to do join when displaying participants)
- MeetingActivityId (foreign key to table MeetingActivity)

Why doesn't deleting from entity work? `entity.Participants.Remove(entity.Participants.First()); ..` Entity framework is tracking entity therefore it should issue delete and insert? Insert actually is issued. But **if `entity.Participants.Add` issues sql insert statement, why `entity.Participants.Remove` won't issue delete statement?**

I must mention that this happens when some records are in Participant table.

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. Participants have a required foreign key which you try to set to null when you remove them from parent entity.

Comment: @MBakardzhiev but I remove the whole entity object Participant in this code: `entity.Participants.Remove`. Shouldn't this mean that ef should issue delete statement `delete from dbo.Participant where Id = x`. It's funny if you type `entity.Participants.Add` ef issues insert sql   statement. Why would then issue delete?

Comment: So your intention is to remove the participants from the database?

Comment: @MBakardzhiev yes, my intention is to delete all participants for this meeting from database

Comment: Ok then, see the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine next scenario:

```
using (var context = new entities.Model1())
{
  // participants are not included - .Include(i => i.Participants)
  var entity = context.MeetingActivities.Single(m => m.ActivityId == 424);

  // as entity.Participants is empty collection, if object state should
  // reflect the one in db, context.SaveChanges() would result next query:
  // delete from dbo.Participant where MeetingActivityId = x as
  // entity.Participants is empty collection.
  // Therefore it makes sense to use context.Participants.Remove/RemoveRange
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Conclusion from example: object state can not reflect changes in db.